# Golangでスライスの型を変更する

Tags: go

Goでスライスの型を変換したいのですが・・・
下のように[]int型のスライスがあり、それを[]float64型に変換したいと思っています。
forループをつかって1つずつ取り出し、それを[]float64型のスライスに追加していく方法もありますが、そのスライス自体の型を変えるにはどうすればいいですか?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    int_slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    //int_sliceを[]float64型のスライスにしたい
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

スライスの型を直接変換する方法はありません。  
forループを使って一つずつ変換するのが一般的です。

```
package main

func intToFloat64(i []int) []float64 {
    f := make([]float64, len(i))
    for n := range i {
        f[n] = float64(i[n])
    }
    return f
}

func main() {
    int_slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    float_slice := intToFloat64(int_slice)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

h2so5 さんの回答と同じなのですが、メソッドを作ってみます。

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "reflect"
)

type int_slice_t []int

func (is int_slice_t) float64() []float64 {
  f := make([]float64, len(is))
  for i, v := range is {
    f[i] = float64(v)
  }
  return f
}

func main() {
  int_slice := int_slice_t{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

  float64_slice := int_slice.float64()

  fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(int_slice))
  fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(float64_slice))
  fmt.Printf("%v", float64_slice)
}
```

`int_slice` を `[]int` で作成する場合は、

```golang
int_slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
float64_slice := int_slice_t(int_slice).float64()
```

などとします。